# When I reset my password for my Microsoft account, how do they know what password I've used before?

Tags: authentication, salt

*Assumption used: all password that I've used have been salted with some random elements before hashed and stored somewhere in their database.*

If my previous password exists only as salted-hashes in their database,then when I:

trying to use a previous password during the password reset phase (as I type it into the new password textfield), **how did they know that I was using a previously used password?**

(side note: Please down vote this question if it is not really constructive or thought provoking,so I can take corresponding measures.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They know the value to which your previous password(s) hashed, and the salts used. When you type your old password, they compare it to the old stored passwords.

Answer (score 0):

As atk said, Windows has an option to remember previous passwords. That means the old passwords are still stored, but they can not be used to authenticate the user.

This feature can be controlled using the Local Security Policy editor, at least in Windows 7. I am not sure about Windows 8, but it would be reasonable to assume it works the same way.

Navigate to `Account Policies` and click on `Password Policy`. You will see a key named `Enforce password history`. By changing the value of this key you can set how many past passwords Windows remembers. Setting it to 0 will disable the feature.